# WPF Binding itemscontrol child controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a user control that I'm using across several pages which defines a header label and two buttons. I want the control to be able to have child controls, but I ran into the problem of binding those child controls since they are in an itemscollection. When I add bindings to the child controls in XAML they are not registered.

Error output: `System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=MyPage'. BindingExpression:Path=MyText; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')`

Excess code omitted for brevity.

e.g.

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl" Name="MyControl">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=MyControl}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind

```
[ContentProperty("Items")]
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty.AddOwner(typeof (MyControl));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable) GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public ItemCollection Items
    {
        get { return ItemsControl.Items; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Page x:Class="MyPage" Name="MyPage">
    <MyControl>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyText,
                        ElementName=MyPage,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </MyControl>
</Page>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class MyPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myText;
    public string MyText
    {
        get{ return _myText; }
        set
        {
            _myText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyText");
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to databind the TextBox to the `MyText` property so that whenever I modify it in the code behind it will get updated on the page.

Comment: have a look at http://drwpf.com/blog/category/itemscontrol/

Comment: This is not a question. What is your problem right now? do you have any exceptions? does it not work as expected? what is the actual behavior you get vs. what you expect?

Comment: Also, your `DependencyObject`-derived classes should not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @HighCore The expected functionality is the Textbox will get bound to the MyPage's MyText property. The actual result is nothing happens.

Comment: Take a look at the Visual Studio output window for binding errors.

Comment: @HighCore There is nothing shown. I have set a breakpoint on the setter of MyText and it never gets called.

Comment: Again, I don't know why you're trying to do this that way, but your `DependencyObject`-derived classes should not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Try setting the Binding Mode=TwoWay, but I don't think it will help. There **should** be errors in the VS output window if the binding is somehow failing.

Comment: Actually I found the error: `System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=MyPage'. BindingExpression:Path=MyText; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')`

Comment: Try changing `ElementName=MyPage` to `Source={x:Reference MyPage}`

Comment: @HighCore `Cannot call MarkupExtension.ProvideValue because of a cyclical dependency. Properties inside a MarkupExtension cannot reference objects that reference the result of the MarkupExtension`

Comment: Then, remove the `x:Reference` and the `ElementName` and try `RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Page}`

Comment: @HighCore That one worked, but there must be a better way to do this... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep, there IS a better way, which is called Model-View-ViewModel. I suggest you research on that.

Comment: @HighCore I don't know how MVVM would work with the way I am reusing the user control.

Comment: MVVM is not about how to reuse controls. MVVM is to understand that **UI is not Data**, therefore your `Page` is not the right place to put your `string` property into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

remove the `ElementName` and try `RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Page}`